# Close tooltip with EventSetter

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying with an event setter to close the tooltip on Preview Mouse Down event.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseDown">
    <EventTrigger.Actions>
        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="myBeginStoryboard">
            <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ToolTip.IsOpen">
                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="False" />
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger.Actions>
</EventTrigger>
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'ToolTip.IsOpen'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parenthesis when specifying an attached property for a `PropertyPath`

See the [MSDN page on Path Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645024(v=vs.95).aspx#attachedanim) for more information

> `<animation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ownerType.propertyName)" .../>`
>
> The parentheses indicate that this property in a PropertyPath should
>   be constructed using an ownerType qualification, not a traversal. It
>   can use an XML namespace to find the type.